# I am getting GET http://localhost:81/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am building a real time chat application .i am using socket.io & node.js 
This is my sever.js file ..

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:81');socket.on('connect', function({alert('connection established');});
```

and my path information is

```
<script src="http://localhost:81/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

now when i look into directory i saw the socket.io.js path is node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.io.js

if i change my path like

```
<script src="http://localhost:81/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.io.js"></script>
```

then am getting 404 error. else iam getting GET http://localhost:81/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Checking server is running, firewall and antivirus blocking port, or the program.

Comment: I give you common casees of this error. Sorry.

Comment: if i stop the firewall it return the same error.

Comment: I think you should do tiny 'hello world' app. Check if it's running.

Comment: No not display anything ...

Answer (score 0):

Just use it like this: `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`
Paths inside of node_modules are not hosted to be available from browser.

Why not use express app to create the server?
And why not refer to their official documentation: http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Comment: Can i create real time notification and real time chat with that .and also i need to save chat data into my sql database

Comment: The tutorial is for real-time chat. As for saving data to sql db, you can do that when you get the "chatMessage" event on the socket. I suggest you mark this question solved and raise a different one for the additional doubts you have.